# Highchart Marker image hides if large dataset is produced

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have added image as marker in highchart and its working fine when data is low, if data item is increasing then it becomes invisible and unless user zoom-in for that data item it's not visible.

I have mentioned both jsfiddle link below, need quick help on it.

Fiddle with Less Data http://jsfiddle.net/ofd52uj7/

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ofd52uj7/][1]
```

Fiddle with More data http://jsfiddle.net/4tbre6oL/

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/4tbre6oL/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrease `enabledThreshold` property:

```
series: [{
    marker: {
        enabledThreshold: 0
    },
    ...
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/knzg84Lj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.enabledThreshold

Comment: I just want to know if there are any options to have marker in json file itself for this https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/

Comment: Hi @NIket, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve?